# Cannot open type library file: 'msxml4.dll': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, dll

I am trying to import this dll in my code:

```
#import <msxml4.dll>
```

But at every place i have this import, i am getting this error:

```
Error   1415    fatal error C1083: Cannot open type library file: 'msxml4.dll': No such file or directory...
```

What are the causes of this `.dll` missing. Code use to work fine before untill in resintalled windows and now trying to build it again.

Comment: Do you have the .dll file in your source file or copied into the Windows directory ?

Comment: May be [How To Fix Msxml4.dll Not Found or Missing Errors](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/msxml4-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm) will help.

Answer (score 3):

I have a c++ project upgrading from vs 2012 to vs2015, and got same error c1083.

## Explanation

This is because `msxml4.dll` cannot be found. (for me instead of being in windows\system32 folder, it was in temporary protected folder. )

(I confirmed with -

```
dir /s /b/ msxml4.dll
```

## Solution

Is to [install msxml4 service pack 2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19662) or [msxml4 service pack 3](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=36292)

... worked for me.

Comment: And I have use the "dir /s /b/ msxml4.dll" and did not find it.  Actually, the msxml4.dll is not in windows\system32 folder, it is in temporary protected folder. You'd better to install msxml4 service pack 2.....

Answer (score 0):

1. Search Where msxml4.dll is present in your code base or c:

   dir /s /b msxml4.dll
2. is you find any paths in step 1,add that path to Additional Library Directories of Your Project.

   2.1 Right Click on Project > Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories
   2.2 Add Path to Additional Library Directories